# C# - Process.Start adding spaces and speech marks around text

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a Process.Start statement below:

```
Process.Start("schtasks.exe", @"/Create /SC DAILY /TN" + "\"" + textBox2.Text + "\"" + @"/TR C:\Program Files\test\scanner.exe 'C:\'");
```

Although I an unable to add speech marks (") around C:\Program Files\test\scanner.exe without throwing errors.

And also unable to add spaces around textBox2.Text, since the output comes out like:

... /Create /SC DAILY /TNtesting/TR/.....

where "testing" is the textBox2.Text

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to [shell injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_injection#Shell_injection)!

Comment: I am pro security expert, no worries ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put *double* speech marks, like this :

```
Process.Start("schtasks.exe", @"/Create /SC DAILY /TN" + " \"" + textBox2.Text + "\" " + @"/TR  ""C:\Program Files\test\scanner.exe"" 'C:\'");
```

This is how you escape `"` in a verbatim string.

EDIT: Added space.

Comment: Thanks, but still need a space on either side of textBox2.Text